# How to get screen/phone time in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to find out how to get the screen time, the amount of time spent on the phone, in android. Is there a function for that or do I have to track it myself. I've tried searching for similar question but didn't have any success. How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a base activity and make your starting main activity on which the app is
   killed when the user destroys it and there extend from it.

   long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
   long end = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
2. In the ondestroy of this activity     long total = end-start;
   write this code.

Comment: But wouldn't this just measure time spent on the app? How do I measure overall screen time?

Comment: Try this please : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235646/8411082